# WinAPI CredEnumerate Marshal.PtrToStructure Exception

Tags: vb.net, winapi

I have problems with enumerating Windows Credentials from VB.Net application with WinAPI functions. My code is below.

```
<DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
Private Shared Function CredEnumerate(filter As String, flag As Integer, ByRef count As Integer, ByRef pCredentials As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Function

Public Enum CRED_PERSIST As UInteger
    SESSION = 1
    LOCAL_MACHINE = 2
    ENTERPRISE = 3
End Enum

Public Enum CRED_TYPE As UInteger
    GENERIC = 1
    DOMAIN_PASSWORD = 2
    DOMAIN_CERTIFICATE = 3
    DOMAIN_VISIBLE_PASSWORD = 4
    GENERIC_CERTIFICATE = 5
    DOMAIN_EXTENDED = 6
    MAXIMUM = 7
    ' Maximum supported cred type
    MAXIMUM_EX = (MAXIMUM + 1000)
    ' Allow new applications to run on old OSes
End Enum

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
Public Structure CREDENTIAL_ATTRIBUTE
    Private Keyword As String
    Private Flags As UInteger
    Private ValueSize As UInteger
    Private Value As IntPtr
End Structure

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
Private Class Credential
    Public Flags As UInt32
    Public Type As CRED_TYPE
    Public TargetName As String
    Public Comment As String
    Public LastWritten As ComTypes.FILETIME
    Public CredentialBlobSize As UInt32
    Public CredentialBlob As IntPtr
    Public Persist As CRED_PERSIST
    Public AttributeCount As UInt32
    Public Attributes As IntPtr
    Public TargetAlias As String
    Public UserName As String
End Class


Private Function GetCredentials() As Credential()
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    Dim pCredentials As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
    Dim credentials As List(Of Credential) = New List(Of Credential)
    Dim ret As Boolean = CredEnumerate(Nothing, 0, count, pCredentials)
    If ret <> False Then
        Dim p As IntPtr = pCredentials
        For n As Integer = 0 To count - 1
            If Marshal.SizeOf(p) = 4 Then
                p = New IntPtr(p.ToInt32() + n)
            Else
                p = New IntPtr(p.ToInt64() + n)
            End If
            credentials.Add(Marshal.PtrToStructure(Marshal.ReadIntPtr(p), GetType(Credential)))
        Next
    End If
    Return credentials.ToArray
End Function
```

`Marshal.PtrToStructure` function throws `System.ExecetionEngineException` without any useful information. I suspected with wrong credential structure but it seems correct to me. If you have any idea about what is wrong, I'm waiting your answers.
Thanks

Edit: Thanks to @Zaggler here is my corrected function now it adds credentials to array but whole structure is empty.
Here is new function.

```
Private Function GetCredentials() As Credential()
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    Dim pCredentials As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
    Dim credentials As List(Of Credential) = New List(Of Credential)

    Dim ret As Boolean = CredEnumerate(Nothing, 0, count, pCredentials)
    If ret <> False Then
        Dim p As IntPtr = pCredentials
        For n As Integer = 0 To count - 1
            Dim cred As Credential = New Credential
            Dim pnt As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(cred))
            Try

                If Marshal.SizeOf(p) = 4 Then
                    p = New IntPtr(p.ToInt32() + n)
                Else
                    p = New IntPtr(p.ToInt64() + n)
                End If
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(cred, pnt, False)
                credentials.Add(Marshal.PtrToStructure(pnt, GetType(Credential)))

            Finally
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pnt)
            End Try
        Next
    End If
    Return credentials.ToArray
End Function
```

Comment: Please see [**this**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ca6d5z7(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) article...

Comment: @Zaggler thanks for your answer. I edited my snippet according source that you provided now i have different problem. Returned Credential structure is empty. I edited my main post.

Comment: Oh i have to use CredRead function after CredEnumerate function.

Comment: Make sure its after the `CredEnumerate`... Also can you set one of the properties for the structure just to test? For example after this `Dim cred As Credential = New Credential` try `cred.TargetName = "TEST"`... Then after the `credentials.Add` what does it look like in that list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first attempt was better.  Don't use AllocHGlobal and FreeHGlobal.  Winapi is allocating memory.  Lookup CredFree to release allocated memory (after marshalling structs).

There is a mistake in your pointer arithmetic.  You have to increment with pointer size so try:

```
...
Dim p As IntPtr = pCredentials
For n As Integer = 0 To count - 1
  credentials.Add(Marshal.PtrToStructure(Marshal.ReadIntPtr(p), GetType(Credential)))
  p = p + IntPtr.Size
Next
...
```

UInt32 and UInteger are the same, so be consistent and choose one.

You could try to use Charset.Auto for everything, if that doesn't work, try Charset.Unicode and use CredEnumerateW function.